# Run a second MySQL query based on results in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

**EDIT:** I've just thought I could run this as one query with something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM clubs
JOIN match_request_archive
ON (SELECT COUNT (clubs.id) AS requests FROM match_request_archive)
```

I appreciate though my syntax is horrendous I've just whipped this up and will tweak it now.

---

I have a basic script for displaying data in a table. I've got a problem I can't solve which is I need to run one simple query to show all the data to the user. But in the last column I need to run a separate query to get the result.

Basically the first column in my table has the unique ID of a Rugby Club on the database. In a separate table on the database is a list of all requests made by clubs to players. I want to display how many requests each club has made in the last column of my script below which means running this query:

```
SELECT * FROM match_request_archive WHERE club_id LIKE "$row['id']"
```

The $row['id'] is from the PHP script below:

```
<?php
include 'credentials.php';

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM clubs";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())

    {

        echo "
        <tr>
        <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['club_name'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['club_captain'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['club_captain_number'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['club_captain_email'] . "</td>
        <td>TBC</td>
        </tr>
        ";
    }
} else {
    echo "<tr><td>0 results</td></tr>";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

To solve this I tried embedding a second script in the echo command but it's my understanding you can't do this and in any case it did cause a fatal error. I can run this query separately and have it displayed in a different table, my problem is I need this to be all in one table. I hope that all makes sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Executing query in loop is bad practice because it has very slow performance.
So you should try get all data by one query if it possible:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) FROM clubs
LEFT JOIN match_request_archive
ON match_request_archive.club_id = clubs.id
GROUP BY clubs.id
```

Comment: Thank you that is almost perfect. The only thing I'm unsure of is I need a number for how many times each clubs.id appears in match_request_archive.id - do you know if that's possible?

Comment: Ahh I'm so sorry just one last thing, is there a way so those that don't appear at all would be included with a 0 value? No worries if not I've got a work around

Comment: note that if a given `club_id` does not appear in the `match_request_archive` table, this query will not return a row for that `club`. To say it another way: this query won't return a "zero" count. To allow a zero count to be returned, we would need an outer join, and modify the `COUNT(*)` to COUNT(match_request_archive.club_id)` (Also, we usually avoid an unqualified `*` in the SELECT list). (I'd offer an answer, but this question already has an accepted answer.)

Comment: Oh that was strange timing - I will attempt an outer join then thank you :)

Comment: @spencer7593 that's really capped it off, all works perfectly now thank you :)

Comment: “*” has no place in such a query

Comment: @Strawberry what? we can't use `*`? It is just example and it will be work

Comment: @Strawberry you're sure? try execute it

Comment: @ArtemIlchenko I'm sure. Perhaps you and I have different definitions of 'work'

Comment: @Strawberry we can get any column list, if you think that using `*` in this case is mistake, ok you have the right to do so

Comment: Likewise, you have the right to be wrong. But I don't think the SO community should be promoting such behaviour. ;-)